# get that rows, WHERE `DAYOFMONTH(<date>)` is devidable on 3?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in MYSQL DB with `date` field in `YYYY-mm-dd` format.
i need to get that rows, `DAYOFMONTH(<date>)` is devidable on `3`.

---

Is it possible to do with mysql functions, or i have to write multiple OR conditions? :/

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use modulus.

Something like,

```
WHERE DAYOFMONTH(<date>) % 3 = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE (DAYOFMONTH(<date>) % 3) = 0
```